# Saving files on C

Tags: c

I want to save files on computer.I can use fwrite commands.

But I have to enumarate files,like file01,file02, .. inside in the for cycle while saving using fwrite commands.

So I have to save ;for example ten files (file01,fle02,file03....,file10...)

Could you advise me a simple example code?

Answer (score 3):

Inside a loop you need to

1. build the filaname
2. open the file
3. write data
4. close the file

C99 example (`snprintf()` is "new"), with lots of details omitted

```
for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "file%02d.txt", j + 1);     /* 1. */
    handle = fopen(buf, "w");                             /* 2. */
    if (!handle) /* error */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);          /* 2. */
    w = fwrite(data, 1, bytes, handle);                   /* 3. */
    if (w != bytes) /* check reason */;                   /* 3. */
    fclose(handle);                                       /* 4. */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the files one by one with fopen, something like this:

```
char filename[128]; // (128-1) characters is the max filename length
FILE *file;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    snprintf(filename, 128, "file%02d", i);
    file = fopen(filename);

    // do stuff with file

    fclose(file);
}
```